# Upper triangular matrices proof

Tags: linear-algebra

An excerpt of the proof from Axler

> [image]

I am trying to understand a simple statement that $\lambda_1 = 0 \implies Tv_1 = 0$

If $T = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &1 \\ 
0 & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
y_1
\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
x_2\\ 
y_2
\end{bmatrix}.$ Then

$Tv_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \lambda_1 + y_1\\ 
\lambda_2 y_1
\end{bmatrix}$

Since $\lambda_1 = 0$, we get $Tv_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
\lambda_2 y_1
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0$

Am I reading something wrong?

**EDIT**

I apologize for my extreme belated reply, but I had to read some preliminary results from another book before I could make another honest attempt as so I would not waste everyone's time.

According to my readings and the answers posted below so far. Does that mean that

$$Tv_2 = [v_2]_{(v_1, \dots, v_n)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mu\\ 
\lambda_2\\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$?

Answer (score 2):

In your case $v_1$ is the vector $(1,0)$, i.e. $y_1=0$.

Comment: I am not demanding $(v_1, v_2)$ to be orthogonal.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct: first, the dimension is nowhere established to be two, and second no where it is mentioned the basis is the standard one.

Comment: @sidht You're not multiplying the vectors with the matrix, you're multiplying the $n$-tuples of coefficients to represent a vector in the given base. For the $i$-th basis vector, that is $e_i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, where are you getting $e_i$ from?

Comment: @sidht Standard $n$-tuple with a $1$ in the $i$-th coordinate, and $0$s elsewhere.

Comment: But why does my basis have to be standard basis?

Comment: @sidht It is not technically the standard basis, but *effectively* it is: the first line of the proof amounts to working with respect to this basis, so the working coordinates of $v_1$ really are $(1,0,\ldots,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the fact that the given triangular matrix is the one corresponding to the linear operator **according to the basis** $\,\{v_1,...,v_n\}\,$ , and this means that

$$Tv_1=\lambda_1v_1+0\cdot v_2+\ldots+0\cdot v_n$$

Remember that the matrix corresponding to $\,T\,$ wrt this basis is the **transpose** of the coefficients' matrix, the first line (=the first column of the matrix!) of which is given two lines above.

Comment: I apologize for my basic question (and belated as well), basically your expression comes form the fact that the columns of the matrix is formed by $Tv_k$?

Comment: Yes, indeed so.

Comment: Is my edit also correct?

Comment: I don't think it is, @sidht. What you have is $$Tv_1=\lambda_1 v_1\\Tv_2=*v_1+\lambda_2v_2\\Tv_3=*v_1+*v_2+\lambda_3v_3\;,\ldots$$

Comment: Yes and it is in the span of the previous vectors (last lines in picture)

Comment: So what is wrong with it?